# FindWindowEx class/title help

Tags: c, button, click

I'm programming in C, and I'm remotely clicking a button programically. I've done it in simple, various simple form applications.. but I've ran across a problem.

```
HWND WINAPI FindWindowEx(HWND hwndParent, HWND hwndChildAfter, LPCTSTR lpszClass, LPCTSTR lpszWindow);
```

I've tried using Spy++ (My old 6.0 edition) and the much-more-friendly WinID tool.

An example would be this; I'm attempting to find the required class and 'window' inside of calc.exe. In Windows 7, the class of these buttons is just "Button". Alright, but when you look for the title, it's "" (NULL). How would I get past this? I've got the ID of the button, but how would I use the ID instead of the "window" title?

If you don't understand what I'm trying to say, let me see if I can simplify it;
I have the class name, but I don't have the title. How can I select a hwnd to a window if I don't have the title (however I do have the ID)?

Comment: This reeks of fragile code that could break in the next version of Windows.  What exactly are you doing?  Why are you trying to programmatically click on a button?

Comment: It seems like something interesting to me; to be able to automate a task like a macro program. It's just a 'fool around see what you can do' thing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the ID of the button, just use [`GetDlgItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645481%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get its handle:

```
HWND hButton = GetDlgItem(hParent, buttonID);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response; I've attempted to use the button id with your function, however, it sparks an error and when I use GetLastError and all that, I only get the useless "The operation completed successfully." EDIT: I tried it on another application, using your method and it worked. However, this doesn't work on all applications. Would you happen to know the cause? Maybe permissions?

Comment: @Saustin: It should work as long as you have the correct parent handle and ID. Sometimes the actual control can be nested within another child window, so you may be getting the parent wrong.

Comment: I had no slightest thought that could occur. Thanks!